# Conversion between docx / doc / rtf and lightweight markup

Tags: ms-word, cross-platform, markup, docx

I am looking for a tool or set of tools to convert between file formats D and M where

- D is a format handled by MSWord, in order of preference, docx, doc, rtf
- M is a lightweight markup, such as markdown, textile, txt2tags, it can be an esoteric one
- there is a way to generate html from M
- conversion is two-way, it's done both from D to M, and from M to D
- utf-8 encoding is handled properly
- the content is simple, paragraphs, some simple formatting like bold and italics, maybe lists
- the tools are platform-independent

What I've found so far

- TeX, LaTeX -- too heavyweight
- [docx2txt](http://docx2txt.sourceforge.net/) -- too lightweight, it supports no formatting at all
- html -- MSWord produces bloated html
- a few one-way conversions, like [doc to mediawiki](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension%3aWord2MediaWikiPlus),

UPDATE:

The use case is a document workflow between technical and non-technical people

- I, the technical guy edit a document in plain text, put it into version control, etc.
- I send it to my manager or other non-technical people
- They add comments, make changes to it using their Word, then they send it back to me
- I want to simply grok their changes, make my changes, put it into version control, without having to use Word

Comment: Why?  Why not just use lightweight markup and create PDF's from it?  Why continue to use Word at all?

Comment: @S.Lott - To communicate with the rest of the world.

Comment: Isn't plain text and PDF more universal than Microsoft file formats?  Who is this "rest of the world"?

Comment: OK, 90% of people edit plain text files and convert them to universal Adobe Pdf. The old-fashioned, technically illiterate 10% use Word to take a note. I want to communicate with that 10%, including my partner, my mom, my boss.

Comment: Are you saying that the other 10% cannot use learn to use notepad?  I don't get this "communicate with" and the very complex two-way conversion requirements in this question.  Why are all these conversions necessary?  Why not simply exchange word documents with the 10% that can't use notepad?

Comment: Because I belong to the 90% that stopped using Word a long time ago, just as you suggested. Is this conversation helping you in answering my question or you're just having fun?

Comment: @Adam Schmideg: I'm still trying to understand the use cases.  Clearly, you're not interested in explaining.  I'll ask one last time.  "Why are all these conversions necessary?"  "I don't get this "communicate with" and the very complex two-way conversion requirements in this question."  You can continue to not answer.  In which case, I'll stop asking, also.

Comment: Where in the world are you guys getting this 90%/10% thing? Do you *really* believe you're even close to the real penetration and usage rates of Office?

Comment: @Otaku: "you guys" (plural)?  Not me.  I don't even get the basic use case.  I use a lightweight markup (RST, specifically) daily, and I never "exchange" with office products.  I just given PDF's.  One way.  All the office products I've ever seen work with plain text files, so there's no convert there.  I can't understand the two-way part of this.  The "90%" figure didn't seem to be part of the use case.  I thought it was just hyperbole and was willing to let it go so I could understand the use case.

Comment: @S.Lott - sorry, dude, I thought the use case was obvious, I face it every other they.  I updated the post to include it.

Comment: @S.Lott - be real. Please. The 90% figure is a joke, since it is really the other way round. Everybody and their grandmother uses Office. Purists don't like that, but hey, this is the real world we are talking about.

Comment: @Adam Schmideg: Here's a hint.  When someone asks about the use case, it isn't obvious.  Here's another hint.  When someone asks about the use case, you have to think that they're unfamiliar with your day-to-day life and need some details.  Here's another hint.  If you want detailed, useful answers, you need to provide a detailed question.  Just suggesting that you can improve your question or you can call the people who are trying to help you idiots.  The choice is yours.

Comment: @Daren Thomas: "be real"?  I said that I assumed the 90% figure was hyperbole.  What more do I have to say?

Comment: OK, people, thanks for the hints, I updated my question, I hope it's clear enough now.  The 90% figure was a joke/hyperbole, of course.

Comment: Word offers a feature called "Track Changes". Clients I've dealt with are very much used to leveraging it in their workflow. "Track Changes" is why it is so much more difficult to replace Word with something else

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adam, I've used docx4j to convert docx to html, edit the html in CKEditor, and then use docx4j to convert the html back to docx.  My process made some assumptions about the css (ie it was designed to handle docx4j's clean html, and editing in CKEditor).

You don't say whether there is a way to generate M from HTML?

Answer (score 1):

I think that Pandoc much more than meet all requirements.

http://pandoc.org

Answer (score 0):

This is probably hard to do two-way, since you will have impedance mismatches between the various formats.

The best world I can think of would be a sort of Wiki / Word hybrid: Maybe you can get Google Wave to do that for you?

Another solution that might work is a CMS like Plone (did they ever add WYSIWIG capability? I stopped caring after version 1). Keep your documents there. Let the system handle changes, annotations etc. You can automate retrieval of the source (should be ReStructuredText) and commit that to your source control if you have to.

Answer (score 0):

This script I wrote might help you in your workflow:

https://github.com/matb33/docx2md

It is a command-line PHP script that will only work with `.docx` files. It will extract the XML, run some XSL transformations, and provide you the result in Markdown format.

I encourage you to send me `.docx` files that don't convert accurately. I'd love to make this script as robust and reliable as possible.